# json adding new element and updating old element using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

i have  user input field with different variables, this means that the user can enter a lot of different values. and I want to save those values under the id of the object assigned to them. When adding them in a json variable, only one instance of the objects is added, any later insertion results in an update in the current variable.

```
 var items = {id: `${ID}`, name: `${name}`}
```

i want the json variable to be saved as an array in a file like this

```
 var items = [
              {id: `${ID}`, name:`${name}`},
              {id: `${ID}`, name:`${name}`}
             ]
```

also I don't want an item to be added if there is already one with the same id instead it would better when it updated

Comment: Do you want it to be added to array on the click of the button ?

Comment: yes i have a save button that call the function where the json is

Comment: I posted the answer , please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go , this is generic solution.

```js
function AddToItems() {

  var length = (document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").length);
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  var items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    items.push({
      id: elements[i].id,
      name: elements[i].value
    });
  }
  console.log(items);
}
```

```html
Input1: <input type="text" id="input_1"/>
Input2: <input type="text" id="input_2"/>
Input3: <input type="text" id="input_3"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="AddToItems()">
Submit
</button>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but in my case, the variables arent just the input but also the image they are attached to it. (ie. user gives image name or title),i want them to be stored as per image not per input. and the user can add as many images as he want..so i cant predict the times to loop the .push function. If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: As per question , it was mentioned the inputs ,so I went ahead and gave the solution. If that is the case I will suggest using document.querySelectorAll(<here you can pass different tags>). For reference , check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this

```js
let id=document.getElementById("id")
let Name=document.getElementById("name")
let insert=document.getElementById("insert")


data=[]

insert.addEventListener("click",()=>{
     ID=id.value
     name=Name.value
      console.log("clicked")

   
var items = {id: `${ID}`, name:`${name}`}
    // data.forEach(ele => {
     if(!data.some(x=>x.id==ID)) data.push(items) 
     else{
     data.forEach(ele =>{
       if(ele.id==ID) data.splice(data.indexOf(ele),1),data.push(items)
     })

     }
   
console.log(data)

})
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="banner-message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <input id="id">
      <input id="name">
    <button id="insert">Change color</button>
  
  </div>
  
</body>
```